# Wiring for a smart switch

Tags: electrical

I've got a Smart Switch which sits behind a standard dumb rocker.

[image]

My issue is that I have the loop going through the switch rather than the ceiling rose. This has confused me and I can't seem to get the wiring correct.

I have 3xLive and 3xNeutral. 1 Live/Neutral pair is to the ceiling rose, 1 is the previous light in the circuit and 1 is the next light in the circuit.

I tried wiring all three neutrals into N and the previous/next live into L1 but that doesn't seem to do it.

How do I wire this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three neutrals indeed go to N.
The live to the light goes to L1.
The previous/next live goes to L and to the dumb switch.
The other side of the dumb switch gets connected to S1.